# What are good sites for purchasing a bulk of typefaces?

Tags: typefaces

I'm a logo designer, and I'm working in a company. As a result of I'm an employee all typefaces are available for free to be used in my work and licensed to my company. Recently I'm working as a freelancer, and I need a lot of typefaces to create several logos.

**I need a site that can allow me to purchase a bulk of typefaces (100 or more) for commercial purposes, for a good price.**

Comment: Adobe Font Folio 11 Contains over 2,400 fonts.... http://www.adobe.com/products/fontfolio.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need commercial fonts (due to specifically requiring one) I quite like to use myfonts.com as they have a large range and their site works nicely.

There are a few "important" fonts that you could buy just as a starter including big names like Futura, Helvetica, Myriad, Franklin Gothic, Garamond, Caslon, etc (some/many of these you may already have bundled with your graphic design software or OS).

Remember you don't have to buy all weights of a font, just the common ones you're likely to use.

Also remember that owning a license to these fonts does not give you the right to embed them in web pages (or PDFs, etc).  For that you need to buy separate web fonts licenses for each use.

Comment: #thomasrutter regarding to the fonts, I will purchase Franklin Gothic and Helvetica, but what do you think is the most important one or common one of those two names.

Comment: Helvetica is much more common.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options. In order of your level of awesomeness:

1. Create your own type.
2. Don't worry so much about variety, just focus on customizing the quality type you can afford.
3. Download a bunch of junk from a site like [FontSquirrel](http://WWW.fontsquirrel.com)* and churn out lots of mediocre logotypes.

The most reasonable option is number 2. You don't need a lot of fonts, you need a good head for conceptual development.

**It's not all bad ;)*

Answer (score 0):

Open source is the future! Check [google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). There are a lot of type face designers that done a awesome job designing and the best part is they let you use it for free!

Keep in mind there is a lot of junk there to but you have to sort it for your self.

Comment: Types should be free...if 1 person out of many billions of people make it first, it is suddenly illegal for rest of other designers billion designers to use it without his/her consent. Everything is the matter of time. In past maybe it was a good idea to have prices so quality would increase by profit and competition but due to increasing population everything is just a matter of time.

Answer (score 0):

Do fine chef's ask where they can buy bulk produce for their fine meals? No. The reason is that bulk is usually not a good indicator of quality. A quality chef will instead figure out what is fresh at the market that day that best fits his menu design.

There's no reason to purchase a typeface for a logo until that particular logo project comes around and a particular typeface fits the requirements. At that time, buy the font for that particular project. Over time, you will end up with a quality set of typefaces rather than 100 cheaply made ones.

While perhaps not true in every industry, in typeface design, 'bulk' usually means 'crap'. There are plenty of 1000 fonts for $99 CDs out there, but if that's all you can afford, then you're not charging enough for your logo design work to begin with.